# JSON to CSV File Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, csv

I am trying to convert the following JSON to CSV via Ruby, but am having trouble with my code.  I am learning as I go, so any help is appreciated.

```
require 'json'
require 'net/http' 
require 'uri' 
require 'csv'

uri = 'https://www.mapquestapi.com/search/v2/radius?key=Imjtd%7Clu6t200zn0,bw=o5-layg1&radius=3000&callback=processPOIs&maxMatches=4000&origin=40.7686973%2C-73.9918181&hostedData=mqap.33882_stores_prod%7Copen_status%20=%20?%20OR%20open_status%20=%20?%20OR%20open_status%20=%20?%7CExisting,Coming%20Soon,New%7C' 

response = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(uri)) 

struct = JSON.parse(response.body.scan(/processPOIs\((.*)\);/).first.first)  


CSV.open("output.csv", "w") do |csv| 
  JSON.parse(struct).read.each do |hash| 
    csv << hash.values
  end
end
```

The error I receive is:

```
from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `new'
from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
from test.rb:14:in `block in <main>'
from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/csv.rb:1273:in `open'
from test.rb:13:in `<main>'
```

I am trying to get all the data off of the following link and put it into a CSV file that I can analyse later.  https://www.mapquestapi.com/search/v2/radius?key=Imjtd%7Clu6t200zn0,bw=o5-layg1&radius=3000&callback=processPOIs&maxMatches=4000&origin=40.7686973%2C-73.9918181&hostedData=mqap.33882_stores_prod%7Copen_status%20=%20?%20OR%20open_status%20=%20?%20OR%20open_status%20=%20?%7CExisting,Coming%20Soon,New%7C

Comment: What specific trouble are you having?

Comment: It just is not writing to the CSV. I keep getting an error pointing to the JSON.parse(struct) line.

Comment: What error are you getting? Are you sure that `response.body` is what you expect it to be? Have you checked that `response.body.scan(/processPOIs\((.*)\);/)` actually is JSON?

Comment: Getting the error :in 'block in <main>'. As I mentioned I am new to all of this.  I thought that   response.body.scan converted the JSON to a text string.

Comment: There's more to the error than that. `'where is pancakes house?'` is a string but not JSON, `'{"where is":"pancakes house?"}'` is a string and JSON.

Comment: Your question is missing a few important things, including: 1. The *complete* error message, including the stack trace; 2. What the value of `response.body` is; and 3. What output you want. Please edit your question to include all of this information. Comments are not a good way to add information to your question.

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems here, the most significant of which is that you're calling `JSON.parse` twice. The second time you call it on `struct`, which was the result of calling `JSON.parse` the first time. You're basically doing `JSON.parse(JSON.parse(string))`. Oops.

There's another problem on the line where you call `JSON.parse` a second time: You call `read` on the value it returns. As far as I know `JSON.parse` does not ordinarily return anything that responds to `read`.

Fixing those two errors, your code looks something like this:

```
struct = JSON.parse(response.body.scan(/processPOIs\((.*)\);/).first.first)

CSV.open("output.csv", "w") do |csv| 
  struct.each do |hash| 
    csv << hash.values
  end
end
```

This ought to work *iif* `struct` is an object that responds to `each` (like an array) and the values yielded by `each` all respond to `values` (like a hash). In other words, this code assumes that `JSON.parse` will return an array of hashes, or something similar. If it doesn't—well, that's beyond the scope of this question.

As an aside, this is not great:

```
response.body.scan(/processPOIs\((.*)\);/).first.first
```

The purpose of `String#scan` is to find every substring in a string that matches a regular expression. But you're only concerned with the first match, so `scan` is the wrong choice.

An alternative is to use `String#match`:

```
matches = response.body.match(/processPOIs\((.*)\)/)
json = matches[1]
struct = JSON.parse(json)
```

However, that's overkill. Since this is a JSONP response, we know that it will look like this:

```js
processPOIs(...);
```

...give or take a trailing semicolon or newline. We don't need a regular expression to find the parts inside the parentheses, because we already know where it is: It starts 13 characters from the start (i.e. index 12) and ends two characters before the end ("index" -3). That makes it easy work with `String#slice`, a.k.a. `String#[]`:

```
json = response.body[12..-3]
struct = JSON.parse(json)
```

Like I said, "give or take a trailing semicolon or newline," so you might need to tweak that ending index depending on what the API returns. And with that, no more ugly `.first.first`, and it's faster, too.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody for the help.  I was able to get everything into a CSV and then just used some VBA to organize it the way I wanted.

```
require 'json'
require 'net/http' 
require 'uri' 
require 'csv'

uri = 'https://www.mapquestapi.com/search/v2/radius?key=Imjtd%7Clu6t200zn0,bw=o5-layg1&radius=3000&callback=processPOIs&maxMatches=4000&origin=40.7686973%2C-73.9918181&hostedData=mqap.33882_stores_prod%7Copen_status%20=%20?%20OR%20open_status%20=%20?%20OR%20open_status%20=%20?%7CExisting,Coming%20Soon,New%7C' 

response = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(uri)) 

matches = response.body.match(/processPOIs\((.*)\)/)
json = response.body[12..-3]
struct = JSON.parse(json)

CSV.open("output.csv", "w") do |csv| 

    csv << struct['searchResults'].map { |result| result['fields']}
  end
```